# How to represent spaces in Perl's DBI properly

Tags: perl, informix, dbi, dbaccess

I have a record in an Informix table. The table columns look like this:

```
acct_no integer,
suffix char(1),
meter_num char(20),
date_read datetime year to second not null ,
counter smallint,
reading integer not null ,
typeofread char(1),
estimated char(1),
time_billed datetime year to second
```

Using Informix's dbaccess tool:

```
select * 
from ws_mtrread 
where acct_no = 113091000 
and suffix = " " 
order by date_read desc;
```

this result (newest shown) is returned and works whether or not I use one or two spaces for suffix.

```
acct_no      113091000
suffix
meter_num    34153205
date_read    2013-09-09 23:31:15
counter      0
reading      1240
typeofread   g
estimated
time_billed  2013-10-22 11:48:21
```

However, this Perl DBI query

```
my $sql_statement = 
"select * ".
"from ws_mtrread ".
"where acct_no = ? ".
"and suffix = ? ".
"order by date_read desc ; ";
```

does not work. I can fetch the row without specifying $suffix, so I know the row exists.

I believe this is an error on my part in representing the suffix. In this example suffix is equal to a string of two spaces.

How do I represent spaces correctly, so the query works? Here is the rest of the code I used to fetch the row.

```
my $test_acct_no = 113091000;
my $suffix = "  ";

my $pt_sel_hdl = $DBHdl->prepare($sql_statement);

$pt_sel_hdl->execute($test_acct_no, $DBHdl->quote($suffix));

my $ws_mtr_read_rec_ref = $pt_sel_hdl->fetchrow_hashref;
```

After the call, $ws_mtr_read_rec_ref is undefined.

Comment: I'll try it, but here's a question. Informix accepts a semicolon to terminate a string. Why would that be a problem?

Comment: @Barmar This is Informix, not MySQL.

Comment: I'm not sure how to represent errstr(). It's coming up undefined if i use as you've listed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use DBI's `quote` method here:

```
$pt_sel_hdl->execute($test_acct_no, $DBHdl->quote($suffix));
```

When you use `?` placeholders in your SQL, the database driver will correctly parameterize the query arguments that you pass to `execute`. You are probably creating a query that is searching for the literal string `"  "` (including the quotes) when you want to search for  (just two spaces.)

So this should be all you need:

```
$pt_sel_hdl->execute($test_acct_no, $suffix);
```

Comment: right. quote() is for when you do not use placeholders, and want to interpolate your argument straight into the SQL statement with the enclosing quotes.

Comment: @runrig I'm slowly changing all my $sql_statement variables to use placeholders. Informix 4GL works with embedded values or placeholders, so I'm used to two methods. I usually use prepared statements with placeholders in 4GL.